# Add an XML node to the existing XML node

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I am working on a script where the objective is to read data from excel and parse it into XML. There is a need for mapping a few of the details under one node if it exists. Considering the below data, I am looking to map the spouse under the subscriber if member id of both of them matches.

[image]

expected output:

```
<Member>
  <MemberDetail>
    <FIRSTNAME>Kevin</FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNAME>Adams</LASTNAME>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Dependent>
      <FIRSTNAME>Kelly</FIRSTNAME>
      <LASTNAME>Adams</LASTNAME>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </Dependent>
  </MemberDetail>
</Member>
```

current output:

```
<Member>
  <MemberDetail>
    <FIRSTNAME>Kevin</FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNAME>Adams</LASTNAME>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </MemberDetail>
  <MemberDetail>
    <Dependent>
      <FIRSTNAME>Kelly</FIRSTNAME>
      <LASTNAME>Adams</LASTNAME>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </Dependent>
  <MemberDetail>
</Member>
```

code:

```
const xlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');
const builder = require('xmlbuilder');
const fs = require('fs');
const doc = builder.create('Member');
const serializer = new (require('xmldom')).XMLSerializer;

xlsxFile('./data/file.xlsx', { sheet: 'Details' }).then((rows) => {
const typeColumn = rows[0].indexOf('MEMBER TYPE');
rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        if (rowIndex !== 0) {
            const detail = employeeList.ele('MemberDetail').att('for', 'subscriber')
            if (row[typeColumn] == 'SUBSCRIBER') {
                row.forEach((cellValue, cellIndex) => {
                    detail.ele(rows[0][cellIndex].split(" ").join(""))
                        .txt(cellValue ? cellValue.toString() : 'empty')
                        .up()
                })
            }
            else {
                const dependentDetail = detail.ele('Dependent').att('for', 'dependent')
                row.forEach((cellValue, cellIndex) => {
                    dependentDetail.ele(rows[0][cellIndex].split(" ").join(""))
                        .txt(cellValue ? cellValue.toString() : 'empty')
                        .up()
                })
            }
        }
    })
    fs.writeFile('./test.xml', serializer.serializeToString(doc), function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error', error)
        }
        else {
            console.log('Your file has been saved')
        }
    })
})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/giOUj.png
```

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would be to isolate the element that you are mapping 'MemberDetail' as a constant and add dependentDetail to that.

try this

```
const xlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');
const builder = require('xmlbuilder');
const fs = require('fs');
const doc = builder.create('Member');
const serializer = new (require('xmldom')).XMLSerializer;

xlsxFile('./data/file.xlsx', { sheet: 'Details' }).then((rows) => {
  const typeColumn = rows[0].indexOf('MEMBER TYPE');
  rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    if (rowIndex !== 0) {
      const detail = employeeList.ele('MemberDetail').att('for', 'subscriber')
      row.forEach((cellValue, cellIndex) => {
        if (row[typeColumn] == 'SUBSCRIBER') {
          const subscriber = detail.ele(rows[0][cellIndex].split(" ").join(""))
            .txt(cellValue ? cellValue.toString() : 'empty')
            .up()
          row.forEach((cellValue, cellIndex) => {
            if (row[typeColumn] !== 'SUBSCRIBER') {
              const dependentDetail = subscriber.ele('Dependent').att('for', 'dependent')
              dependentDetail.ele(rows[0][cellIndex].split(" ").join(""))
                .txt(cellValue ? cellValue.toString() : 'empty')
                .up()
            }
          })
        }})
  fs.writeFile('./test.xml', serializer.serializeToString(doc), function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error', error)
    }
    else {
      console.log('Your file has been saved')
    }
  })
}})
  .catch(err => console.log(err))})
```